# how to add column to existed sqlite virtual table

Tags: sqlite

I am not familiar with the sqlite
I need to add a column to the existed virtual table.
How do I add column? Or the virtual table just cannot be alter ... add column.
Then do I need to create a new virtual table?

Comment: it turns out I have to recreate a new virtual table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN` on a virtual table.

Recreating a virtual table is dependent on what the virtual table is (i.e. the part you put in the `USING` clause), because that defines the virtual table's implementation and semantics.

See [The Virtual Table Mechanism of SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html) for more info.